# Is it correct to use php header() function within require/include functions?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to set the encoding and other parameters in php by using `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` but I'm not sure if the correct approach is to do it at the beggining of each php file like:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
...
```

or if I can do with a function in an external file like helpers.php:

```
<?php 
   function initialize(){
       header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
       mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
       mb_language('uni');
       ...
   }
```

and in my main.php file simply do:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'helpers.php';
    initialize();
    ...
?>
```

And last but not least:
If I do set the `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` correctly in my main.php, do I need to put that header(...) or call to initialize() within every file that I need to require starting from that main.php.

I need to know what's the right way to do this

Comment: Does it work when you do it?

Comment: What is main.php?  Is it your front gateway to your app?

Comment: Just remember headers must be sent before script output.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, by calling initialize() it sets the header correctly, but I don't know if my approach is correct because http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-description says "t is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called"

Comment: @Progrock main.php is a name that I've just used to give an example, it can be the main file of my webapp

Comment: The comment in the manual is highlighting an easy mistake, it's easy to inadvertently cause output.  Nothing wrong with the include or require.

Comment: @Progrock, and what about other required files, they also need to have that header(); or it's inherited in some way

Comment: If let us say your main.php is your bootstrap/front gateway to your app, and you send the raw http header, it's done.  If however you had multiple gateways, foo.php, bar.php and baz.php, you'd need to send the header in each.  Have you checked to see existing default headers?  Try `curl -I http://example.com/foo`, sometimes they are set in the server environment.

Comment: @Progrock, ok, thanks for the clarification, I've also added "AddDefaultCharset utf-8" in my .htaccess, because I don't want to have troubles with the data at debugging time. Oh, I forgot to say that I'm working in a shared hosting environment. Thanks again, it's clear for me now.